# AWS CDK compiled javascript code giving - __dirname is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-sam, aws-cdk-typescript

The CDK generates a JS file from my Typescript code. When I try to test the compiled JS code via SAM local invoke I am getting the error:

```
__dirname is not defined in ES module scope"
"stack":["ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope","    at node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/custom-resource-provider/custom-resource-provider.js
```

Other generated functions are working and `__dirname` is not called in the function that I am developing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to the AWS CDK; this is a common problem with ESM modules in Node.

What you can do to get the equivalent of the `__dirname` magic constant, you can do the following:

```
import { fileURLToPath, pathToFileURL } from 'url'
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
```

Comment: The strange thing is that it is in the compiled JS code and I do not use __dirname in any of my code. So it must be coming from an Import but the same imports are used elsewhere with no issue.

Comment: I see, then it might be a bug in the CDK. Maybe raise an issue on the repo?

Comment: Which version of that package are you using?